# What are Scheme Macros?

Tags: macros, lisp, scheme

What are scheme macros?
What are they used for?

I have read about it on wikipedia but still I am not sure about the practical use of macros.

Comment: See the Racket sources for hundreds of the practical examples.

Comment: This question is a bit too broad, and we'd point to a book such as Programming Languages: Application and Interpretation http://www.cs.brown.edu/~sk/Publications/Books/ProgLangs/, around Chapter 35 or so.

Comment: Scheme macros are used mainly for trying to convince people that Lisp macros with gensyms have the kooties. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Macros are useful for language extensions that can't easily be represented as functions. Matthias Felleisen suggests the following three semi-canonical uses for macros:

- changing the order of evaluation (viz: 'or')
- introducing new binding forms (viz: 'let')
- introducing a new data language (viz: 'quote')

For more on these, see [this posting to the LL1 mailing list](http://people.csail.mit.edu/gregs/ll1-discuss-archive-html/msg01539.html)

Answer (score 2):

The most basic usage is syntactic sugar. e.g. when / until

The most common practical usage is lazy execution. e.g. delay

A typical more advanced (because it breaks hygiene) usage are anaphoric special forms.